# Android Permission Dependencies

Tags: android, permissions

I have an APK that exposes an AIDL `Service` interface protected with a custom permission. When my APK is installed before client applications, all works fine.  However, when the reverse is true, i.e. when client applications (with my custom permission in `<use-permission>`) are installed before my APK, SecurityExceptions are thrown.

Is there a way around this?  I've come across [this old google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/kCJN1rj5pMo) but the solution doesn't work for my case.  That is, the client applications cannot declare the permission in their manifests.

Is this not a typical use case?

Comment: "Is there a way around this?" It is (afaik) unfortunately still the case that applications are granted permissions during installation only and only if that permissions was declared before. That is fine for most apps but if your app declares permissions for 3rd party apps than the only way for that to work is to reinstall the 3rd party apps after your is installed & the permission is known to the system

Comment: I got the same problem here and I wonder if there is any way to re-trigger the permissions check, maybe on-boot or something like this...